# implementation of spring oauth 2

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have to implement a OAUTH 2.0 server application , i know how oauth 2.0 works but when i have googled on how to implement, everywhere i am getting spring boot with oauth 2.0 and my requirement is i should give two URL's to the client 
one to get the access_code and second rest call to get the access_token, is there a way that i can get this from spring boot or spring security ? in Memory storage for tokens.

I tried using spring boot oauth examples but none of them are giving separate URL's for access_code and access_token.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you are delivering the API part:
* Client authenticates against an OAuth endpoint and gets an access token
* Client calls API with an access token
* API must validate access token

Typically you'll code the API - and use an out of the box Authorization Server for the OAuth endpoint

To answer your question properly it would help to know what type of client (partner back end / UI etc)

There will be a bunch of messages between client, API and Authorization Server - this post may give you some ideas:
https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/

I may be able to help you with the spring boot stuff once I understand your scenario better

Comment: Sorry for late reply. client would be another java program not UI

Comment: do we have any examples with java implementation?

Comment: So looks like the client will get a token via OAuth Client Credentials flow - by calling the token endpoint of your Authorization server. The client will then send your API the token in the authorization header. Your API will then need to validate the token. The stuff in the above tutoriam link and the one that precedes it can help you to get set up.

Comment: The nimbusds library is very good - have a browse of their website for some examples - here is some code of mine that uses the lib fir token validation: https://github.com/authguidance-examples/authguidance.apisample.javaspringboot/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/api/basicapi/framework/security/OAuthAuthenticator.java